# What is password strength considered enough for use with password_hash function?

Tags: php, security, hash, bcrypt, php-password-hash

As far as I understand, one of the most important features of the new [PHP password hashing extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) (or bcrypt in general) is algorithm's *speed*, which slows brute-force attack method a lot.

But still it runs at some speed, surely enough for the dictionary attack and to brute-force weak passwords, [supposedly] shorter than six alphanumeric characters.

So I want to know, how it's certainly slow, and, particularly - which password strength considered safe to be used with.
"As strong as you can imagine" is not an answer, as password strength is always a trade-off between security and usability - so, I am looking for the minimal strength that can be considered safe and even some future-proof.

Please note that I am a man of practice - so, certain answer based on concrete numbers is way more preferable than long and windy theoretical reasoning with uncertain conclusion.

To clarify a bit more, worst scenario supposed: users database is stolen, and someone would try to decipher passwords. Rainbow tables are not an option thanks to strong salt. 
So, the only vectors left are dictionary attack and brute-force. Assuming we are supplying users with pre-generated passwords, eliminating dictionary attack. This is why password strength is my only concern.

**Update:**
It seems I weren't understood well. The question, to me, is quite **practical**, and fairly **answerable**. And of **great importance**.

Without determining enough password strength, the use of this new algorithm can be questioned. Why bother with good algorithm *if* passwords are still left unsafe? So - it is my strong belief - that along with recommendation for using new hashing algorithm, there should be always a recommendation for the minimum password strength. Which I want to know.

In other words, if there exists particular certainty about one part - algorithm ("use this one, not other!") - there apparently should be certainty about another part - password strength, which can be spoken with same level of authority. Otherwise the weakest part will spoil the strongest one.

Comment: You asked a question, and then you answered it:  "password strength is always a trade-off between security and usability."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've clarified my question.

Comment: I once read this article while redditing :  http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing  I believe for a man of practice like yourself it should be Common sense . but , I recommend it anyways.

Comment: I realize that you're not looking for an academic thesis, but to answer this question one needs to understand the value of what you're trying to protect. The trade off then is to determine how much cost the cracker has to expend to get the value behind the password. To me, the answer would be different on a forum site (low value) vs. my bank website (high value).

Comment: Since brute forcing a password is basically just a matter of throwing processing power at it... services like the Amazon cloud pretty much mean that no password will be entirely "safe" - still it's possibly worth looking at GRC's "how big is your haystack" https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm and chucking some strings in to see what you get.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer there is a thing like Digital signature. It is believed that signature is unbreakable at any level of effort. Or m I wrong with that? Or may be no password of sane size could match a text and thus password is a special case which is inevitable breakable? Anyway, certain numbers are still welcome.

Comment: You are wrong. Anything is crackable given enough time and processing power -- except for '[one time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)' encryption, but even that has vulnerabilities (usually in transmission of the pad).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer okay, the level of security world governments trust in will suit me as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a general security concern and belongs to [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I tried asking a question there once. And since then I wouldn't give a cent for their opinion.

Answer (score 36):

Am not sure if i understand your question clearly but i would just focus on password strength and how it affects brute-force attack.

> But still it runs at some speed, surely enough for the dictionary attack and to brute-force weak passwords, [supposedly] shorter than six alphanumeric characters.

**Introduction**

For a moment forget about hash algorithm (md5, sha , pbkdf2 bcrypt , scrypt , etc)   and lest focus on [Password Strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) first

**Password Strength** [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength)

This is a measure of the effectiveness of a password in resisting guessing and brute-force attacks. In its usual form, it estimates how many trials an attacker who does not have direct access to the password would need, on average, to guess it correctly.

It can simply be calculated as :

[image]

The entropy is given by `H=Llog2N` where `L` is the length of the password and `N` is the size of the alphabet, and it is usually measured in bits.

**Hash Function**

`password_hash` uses `[bcrypt][4]` by default with is sufficient for a password but there are better alternatives such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) for more information on what i mean see [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Using [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) , lets estimate the following

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+
|  HASH  | ESTIMATE  |     BITS/S     |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
| MD5    | 10742M    | 90110427136    |
| BCRYPT | 31M       | 260046848      |
+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

*Please note that is is an estimate and can vary based on hardware capacity*

With this information we can safely calculate how long it would take us to brute force different password

**Calculate Entropy in PHP**

```
$passwords = array(
        "1234",
        "F2A1CC",
        "password",
        "PaSSworD",
        "P4ssw0Rd97",
        "p#aSS*Word14",
        "Dance With Me Tonight" 
);

print("PASSWORD\tLENGTH\tENTROPY\tTIME MD5\tTIME BCRYPT\n");

foreach($passwords as $password ){

    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", 
        $password, 
        strlen($password), 
        $entropy = calculateEntropy($password), 
        totalTime($entropy, "90110427136"),     // Check with MD5
        totalTime($entropy, "260046848")        // Check with BCrypt
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------------+
|       PASSWORD        | LENGTH | ENTROPY |  TIME MD5  |  TIME BCRYPT   |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------------+
| 1234                  |      4 |  13.29  | 1min       | 1min           |
| F2A1CC                |      6 |  24.00  | 1min       | 1min           |
| password              |      8 |  37.60  | 1min       | 1min           |
| PaSSworD              |      8 |  45.60  | 1min       | 1day+          |
| P4ssw0Rd97            |     10 |  59.54  | 2mo+       | 71yr+          |
| p#aSS*Word14          |     12 |  75.86  | 13,479yr+  | 4yr+           |
| Dance With Me Tonight |     21 |  120.29 | 474,250yr+ | 164,335,595yr+ |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------------+
```

[Output Converted using csv2table](https://github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter/tree/master/csv2table)

CUDA/OpenCL implementations of password crackers can leverage the massive amount of parallelism available in GPUs, peaking at [billions of candidate passwords a second](http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm).

Lets Estimate With we can do `921600M c/s` on in parallel on very fast system

```
T = 966367641600 * 8   
T = 7,730,941,132,800  // bits/sec
```

**Using**

```
foreach($passwords as $password ){  
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", 
        $password, 
        strlen($password), 
        $entropy = calculateEntropy($password), 
        totalTime($entropy, "7730941132800")        // Check with Hash
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------+
|       PASSWORD        | LENGTH  | ENTROPY |   TIME   |
+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1234                  |       4 | 13.29   | 1min     |
| F2A1CC                |       6 | 24.00   | 1min     |
| password              |       8 | 37.60   | 1min     |
| PaSSworD              |       8 | 45.60   | 1min     |
| P4ssw0Rd97            |      10 | 59.54   | 20hr+    |
| p#aSS*Word14          |      12 | 75.86   | 157yr+   |
| Dance With Me Tonight |      21 | 120.29  | 5,527yr+ |
+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

As you can see it still takes a while for a decent 12 digit to be broken.

**Function Used**

```
// Calculate Password entropy
// Uses H = L Log2 N
// where L is the length of the password and
// N is the size of the alphabet, and it is usually measured in bits
function calculateEntropy($password) {

    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength
    // Entropy per symbol for different symbol sets
    // Missing All extended ASCII printable characters
    // Missing Diceware word list

    // TODO
    // Larger Character Set
    // '/[\!"#$%&\'\(\)\*\+,\-.\/:;<\=>\?\@\[\]^_`\{|\}~]+/' => 32,
    $cases = array(
            "/\s+/" => 1, // Arabic numerals (0–9) (e.g. PIN)
            "/[0-9]+/" => 10, // Arabic numerals (0–9) (e.g. PIN)
            "/[a-z]+/" => 26, // Case insensitive Latin alphabet (a-z)
            "/[A-Z]+/" => 26, // Case insensitive Latin alphabet (A-Z)
            '/[\!\@#$%\?\&\*\(\)_\-\+=~:;.]+/i' => 18  // Other Character
        );

    $L = strlen($password); // Length of password
    $N = 0; // Character Set

    foreach($cases as $regex => $value ){
        if (preg_match($regex, $password)){
            $N += $value;
        }
    }

    // Don't confuse hexadecimal for alpha numeric characters
    // hexadecimal numerals (0–9, A-F) (e.g. WEP keys)
    if (ctype_xdigit($password)){
        $N = 16;
    }

    // Fix pure number cases that might have been changed by hexadecimal
    // Arabic numerals (0–9) (e.g. PIN)
    if (ctype_digit($password)){
        $N = 10;
    }

    // Using H = L Log2N
    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength
    // Random passwords entropy
    $H = $L * log($N, 2);
    return number_format($H, 2);
}

// Claculate Total time it would take
// Using Entropy & froce / s
function totalTime($entropy, $force) {
    bcscale(0);

    // Total Base on entorpy 2^H
    $total = bcpow(2, $entropy);

    // Time Taken per sec on Force
    $ss = bcdiv($total, $force);

    $time = "";
    $parts = [];

    $parts['yr'] = bcdiv($ss, "31104000");
    $parts['mo'] = bcdiv(bcmod($ss, 31104000), 2592000);
    $parts['day'] = bcdiv(bcmod($ss, 2592000), 86400);
    $parts['hr'] = bcdiv(bcmod($ss, 86400), 3600);

    // Clean Year
    // Can really generate large numbers

    $suffix = "";
    $yr = $parts['yr'];
    if (!empty($yr)){
        if (bccomp($yr, "1000000") > 0){
            $parts['yr'] = bcdiv($yr, "1000000"); // Million
            $year = " million ";
        }

        if (bccomp($yr, "1000000000") > 0){
            $parts['yr'] = bcdiv($yr, "1000000000"); // Billion
            $year = " billion ";
        }

        if (bccomp($yr, "1000000000000") > 0){
            $parts['yr'] = bcdiv($yr, "1000000000000"); // Trillion
            $year = " trillion ";
        }
    }

    foreach($parts as $t => $v ){
        if (empty($v)){
            continue;
        }
        $time .= number_format($v, 0) . $suffix . $t . "+";
        break;
    }

    return empty($time) ? "1min" : $time;
}
```

**Misunderstanding**

You are right password length is important so as the entropy of the password. Most recommendations advice users to use [use bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) , password complexity, etc. without understanding of password strength

But the fact is the simplest passwords can often be the strongest.

[image]

[Source](http://www.xkcd.com/936/) | [Related blog post](http://blog.shay.co/password-entropy/)

> So I want to know, how it's certainly slow, and, particularly - which password strength considered safe to be used with.

[image] 
[Source](http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html)

Definitely not `6 letters` :)

- < 28 bits = Very Weak; might keep out family members
- 28 - 35 bits = Weak; should keep out most people, often good for desktop login passwords
- 36 - 59 bits = Reasonable; fairly secure passwords for network and company passwords
- 60 - 127 bits = Strong; can be good for guarding financial information
- 128+ bits = Very Strong; often overkill

**Conclusion**

Here are some good references you might what to look at

- [The Rainbow Table Is Dead](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/rainbow-table-is-dead.html)
- [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance)
- [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)
- [Don't use bcrypt](http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html)
- [Password Entropy](http://blog.shay.co/password-entropy/)
- [Password Strength/Entropy: Characters vs. Words](http://blog.webernetz.net/2013/07/30/password-strengthentropy-characters-vs-words/)
- [HOW MUCH ENTROPY IN THAT PASSWORD?](https://subrabbit.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/how-much-entropy-in-that-password/)
- [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. So far it's the best one. I have one objection though - I've a prejudice against pass phrases. They cannot be count just by length as though they are random passwords. They are not random. As a matter of fact, four word phrase is just 8000 ^ 4 where 8000 is a vocabulary to pick words from. It's still decent number but not that big as your function counts.

Comment: I disagree, `Dance With Me Tonight` was a basic example but please note its case sensitive. It could as be `Dance With Me on 16tH` or `dancE witH mE @ home` which even has higher entropy. The share size of all possible combination of each word with replication, case sensitivity , possibility of numbers and special characters  does not make brute force a sensible option ... Just use a `keylogger`

Comment: Look, there is something abour comic you posted. "One of the Os was a zero? And there was some symbol"? Sorry, but I am amighty sick from ambiguity of internet knowledge. In one paragraph you are calling one practice bad and it another offers to use it. When you're talking of "words" then it will be words. Not random strings. If you offer to use a passphrase on modified charset, then **PLEASE** state it in your answer. You called it "simpliest". So - make it complex would be unfair. Please be consistent. Thank you.

Comment: Also, to criticize your answer once more. There is an explanation in that comic, why P4ssw0Rd97 cannot be count by it's length as well.

Comment: Looks like an exceedingly informative answer, kudos. I did go ahead and add a link to the _original_ source of the comic you used, while keeping the link to the blog post where you apparently found the comic. I hope you find that appropriate.

Comment: Actually it depends on the cost factor, how fast BCrypt hashes can be calculated, that's the idea behind all key-derivation functions. Calculating the entropy of a password, does not tell how fast a password can be cracked. This applies only for really random passwords, other passwords are often cracked much faster because of clever [attack modes](http://hashcat.net/wiki/#attack_modes).

Answer (score 3):

It is an interesting question, though it is very unlikely that anybody will be able to give a final answer.

As you know, BCrypt (and other key-derivation functions) have a cost factor. Normally you tune this cost factor, until your server needs a certain time for hashing a password, for example 1 millisecond. An attacker with the same hardware could therefore calculate 1'000 hashes/s.

If you compare the speed of [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) (GPU) with its CPU version you see a factor 100 for MD5, so we can guess that an attacker can bruteforce about 1'000'000 hashes/s (BCrypt is not GPU friendly, but to be on the safe side...). That's ways from the 8'000'000'000 MD5 hashes/s and depends on the cost factor.

The second problem is the strongness of the password. If it is part of a common dictionary, it can be found quickly even if it is long, so a minimum length is no   guarantee for a strong password. If it is "random" enough, the only way to crack it, is brute-forcing (the best case for us). For this case we can try some math:

```
Password alphabet: 62 characters (a-z A-Z 0-9)
Combinations to try: half of all possible combinations
Password length 7: 3E12 combinations → 20 days
Password length 8: 2E14 combinations → 3-4 years
```

Of course this is based on a lot of assumptions, maybe the attacker can brute-force much faster, or the password is not this strong. I myself demand a minimum of 8 characters, but recommend to use a passphrase.

**EDIT: One more note about password strength:**

The strength of a password cannot be realistically calculated, surely not by a formula. Every serious password cracker tool will support hybrid attacks and [rule based attacks](http://hashcat.net/wiki/#attack_modes). Passwords looking strong can be very weak, if they are part of a dictionary or are coped by a rule, so it depends on the imagination of the attacker, how fast a password can be cracked.

The only thing we can tell is, that *long and random* passwords are strong, because there is no easier way to crack them than brute-forcing. But this doesn't help here, because the *users* will choose their passwords, not the developer who built a website, and they do not choose ideal passwords.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that at least aims to answer the question, not just reciting some banality - a rare thing on Stack Overflow, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Per your latest comment, you wish to construct a password scheme that would be acceptable to major governments.  This information is readily available.

- [FIPS 112](http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip112.htm), the standards required by the US government.
- [EU Password Guidelines](http://www.eui.eu/ServicesAndAdmin/ComputingService/ComputingAccounts/PasswordGuidelines.aspx)

Comment: Well, no. I am looking not for bureaucratic documents nor for vague guidelines (use 8 to 16 letters). But certain answer based on numbers.

Comment: This might not be what the OP is looking for, but fact is you can't take a stack exchange post to court as a legal defence. If your looking out of curiosity ask on. If your looking because your creating a real system, follow the excepted industry standard an no less.